# Noam Elimelech davened nusach Ashkanaz

Tags: sources-mekorot, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, chassidic-rebbe, nusach-ari

I remember a learning from a certain version of the Noam Elimelech and in the back of the sefer there were letters and other miscellaneous topics. One of the letters was the about the Noam Elimelech explaining how he davened nusach Ashkanaz for many years and then when he become older and felt more ready he switched to nusach Ari. I am having trouble locating that letter,since I dont know which version it was in,does anyone recall where it is?

Comment: I read it years ago,but I what I got from it was that he held Ashkanaz is always good for simple folk,and Nusach Ari is only for those who are on a high level,thats why I am l9oking for the actual text to see what the deal is

Comment: I quoted the letter you addressed and more letters from the som of the Noam Elimelech,

Answer (score 1):

In the book Noam Elimelech, three letters address the nusach sfard usef by chasidim.

I assume that the letter you are remembering is a letter in which the NE explains that when he did become older he realized the goodness of nusach sfard, here is an extract:

> גיה"ק הגיעני ומה שכתב מעלתו אם לשנות הנוסחא ולהתפלל בנוסח ספרד מיום עמדי על דעתי בידיעת ספר ראיתי וגם שמעתי שהיו מתפללים בנוסח ספרד גם רבותי ספרו לי שהיה בימיהם וקודם שהיו עדיין מעטים בימיהם  **והנה אני לא הבנתי את הנוסחא הנ"ל עתה הנה נא זקנתי הבנתי התועלת והמעלה של אותה הנוסחא עד שבלתי אפשרי להעלות על הכתב גודל מעלתה גם אם הייתי במבטא בשפתיי איני יודע בבירור אם היה אפשר להבינו**  אך צריך שיהיה  המתפללים בנוסח הזה פרושים מדרכי העולם הראשון מהפרישה שלא להוציא שקר מפיו ושלא להיות מקלל את חבירו אפילו בני ביתו בשום פעם גם שלא יקפיד עליהם, אפילו הקפדה בלב, ושלא להוציא שבועה מפיו ושלא להיות לו קנאה וחמדת ממון ומדת גאוה בלתי אפשרי להעלות על הכתב גנותי כידוע לכם שאני מוכיח עצמי תמיד ומבייש עצמי ברבים כדי להוציא מכח אל הפועל ושלא להיות משתכר בשום פעם בשום משקה המשכר כי אם מעט לצורך מה גם שיהא מרגיש בעצמו באמת שאין לו שום מנוחה מדאגות מצרות ישראל ולבו כואב ומיצר עליהם מבלי הפוגות עד שמגודל הצער בלתי יכול להתאפק מלתהפלל עליהם בינו לבין עצמו אף שאינו ראוי והגון בעיני עצמו על כללות ישראל ואפילו על שונאיו אם לא שיראה מהם שעוברים על מצוות עשה או לא תעשה ועיקר שיהיה למדן על כל פנים גמרא ותוספות ופירוש רש"י ושאר דרכי הקודם כמבואר בספר עץ חיים ועיקר אהבת חברים ודיבוק חברים ומי שאין בו כל המידות הללו בוודאי אינו מכת זו ומי שיש בו כל המידות הללו אותם בני אדם ראוי וטוב להם להתפלל בנוסח ספרד הגם שידעתי בכם שאינכם עדיין במדרגה זו ככל הצורך אף על פי כן מחמת שאני רואה שנפשכם חשקה מאוד ומתאמצים מאוד לבא בעבודת הבורא יתברך באמת הבא לטהר מסייעין לו והנוסחא זו גם כן מסייע שתוכלו להחזיק בעבודתו יתברך שמו באמת כיון שאתם משתוקקים לבא באמת בחמדה הנ"ל ואם לאו חלילה להתפלל בנוסחא הנ"ל כי הנה ראיתי אנשים גדולים שהם פרושים מדרכי העולם אבל הכל בשביל הנאתם גם יש לומדים בטלית ותפילין אש אין לך פרישות גדול מזה כי באמת הדברים הללו הם טובים אך שאין בהם פנימיות: שלום וישע רב לאהובי או"נ הנצמד בקירות לבי התורני והרבני חכם ומושלם וותיק ועושה חסד כש"ת מו"ה יהודה נ"י ויופיע:‏

In this letter the author says that he already the nusach sfard was already present when he was young. He says that **when he was young he did not understand this nusach, but when he became older, he understand the greatness of this nusach**. He says that this nusach is for spiritually elevated people, or for persons with spiritual elevation ambition and sincerity.

A matter of reflection is the hypothetical presence in central Europe of diverse nusachaot. There are many countries in Europe in which several nusachaot were present. In an other letter of the son of the Noam Elimelech, we can read:

> וידקדק על עצמו כחוט השערה לקיים הכל המבואר בפוסקים ובפרט בשולחן ערוך אורח חיים ובספרי מוסר אשר עודנה חיים בגן עדן  **ואחר כך יתפלל נוסחא זו של הבית יוסף ז"ל**  ובוודאי יטעום בה טעם ולא יהיה יכול להתאפק מלהתפלל נוסחא זו אף שיהיו מתקוטטים עמו לא יחוש ויסבול הכל, וכך אמר אדוני אבי מורי אם תרצו להשגיח בדבריי אלו תראו שדבריי כנים ואמיתיים ומי שיש לו עוד ספקות וקושיות על עובדי השם יתברך

This is also an advise to pray in nusach, called Nusach Bet Yosef, when a great degree of spiritual integrity is reached.

In an other letter, the son of the Noam Elimelech wrote:

> ושאלתי אדוני אבי ומורי נרו יאיר שיאמר לי מאי טעמא משנים הנוסחאות שבתפילה והשיב לי כך הלא הבית יוסף ז"ל שהוא ראש לכל הפוסקים הוא ז"ל מביא אלו הנוסחאות ואחר כך בא הרמ"א ז"ל שהוא גם כן ראש לכל הפוסקים איזן וחיקר כל התיקונים על מכונם לפני כללות ישראל וראה בנוסחא זו שהוא אור גדול ואין העולם כדאי להשתמש בו והעמיד לנו נוסחא אשכנזית שהוא דבר השוה לכל נפש כערכנו  **אבל לפני הצקידים אלו אשר רחצו מצואתם ומדקדקים על עצמם כחוט השערה וודאי לא היה כוונתו ז"ל עליהם לבטל אותם מלהתפלל נוסחא זו שכתב הבית יוסף**  אלו ואלו דברי אלוקים חיים: ואם תשקה לך הלא יש כמה אנשים שאינם במדרגה זו כאשר כתבתי ואף על פי כן מתפללים נוסחא זו ומתחברים לחסידים עליונים וגם הם נקראים בשם חסידים ...‏

We see that according to the version of the history, the both nuschaot were present in Poland and the Rama decided  that the nusach Ashkenaz is more understandable. But the nusach of the Bet Yosef was already present. I assume that the nusach BY is probably the old nusach sepharadi and Arizal did pray in a sepharadic siddur.  The Baal Shem Tov was living in an area closest to the Ottoman Empire. Probably the sepharadic siddurim were known in middle Europa before the advent of chasifism.

**The Noam Elimelech himself perhaps allways prayed Nusach Sfard.**

Comment: Where do you see him saying he always prayed sfard? Don't you think page numbers or letter numbers would be a good idea to add to help anyone find these letters themselves?

Comment: @user6591 Very good, you find the point. We can interpret. "לא הבנתי את הנוסחאות הנ" ל" as a sign of rebellion and a refute to make what they say him to made.  At least he was asked to make this.

Comment: @user6591 anyway the true interest was to enlight those letters and to try to give a possible explanstion on this strange passage regarding BY and RAMA

Comment: @user6591 I changed the last ststement, may be that he ...